# Lambda with BackgroundWorker

Tags: c#, lambda

Why is the following syntax valid?

```
BackgroundWorker bw = new BackgroundWorker();
String one = resultFromSomeMethod();
String two = resultFromOtherMethod();
String three = resultFromThirdMethod();
bw.DoWork += (a,b) => TestMethod(one, two, three);
```

where TestMethod is defined as:

```
private void TestMethod(String one, String two, String three){
   //Do Stuff!!
}
```

The `DoWorkEventHandler` is defined as a delegate that takes two parameters: object sender and EventArgs e. However, the TestMethod above takes no such parameters. By my understanding of a delegate, to create a new delegate the method has to conform to the delegate's declaration. I seem to have bypassed that restriction by using a lambda. How and why does the syntax above work, even though if I try to create a `new DoWorkEventHandler(TestMethod)` it most certainly would not work?

I read Eric White's [blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericwhite/archive/2006/10/03/lambda-expressions.aspx) on Lambda Expressions but it didn't seem to answer this question.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Let me clarify lambda's for you:

```
(a,b) => TestMethod("", "", "");
```

Translates to:

```
private void AnonymousLambda(object a, EventArgs b)
{
    TestMethod("", "", "");
}
```

The syntax of a lambda is:

```
implicit method arguments => method body
```

The implicit method arguments are determined by the expected signature of what the method is being assigned to (or called from). Because you're assigning this lambda expression to the `DoWorkEventHandler` delegate, it automatically interprets `a` and `b` as `object` and `EventArgs` respectively.

In some cases, the compiler cannot infer the implicit types for the parameters of the lambda, so you could also have written them explicitly:

```
(object a, EventArgs b) => TestMethod("", "", "");
```

So you're really calling your TestMethod in the body of another method which you anonymously created! And the outer method has the `DoWorkEventHandler` method signature.

**EDIT**

Per the additional question details about the string variables, the compiler is creating a **closure** over your code to include the variables in the scope of the method. The code basically becomes a new class which holds the variables as private fields and then references them in the call:

```
public class AnonymousClosureClass
{
    public void AnonymousLambda(object a, EventArgs b)
    {
        // Note the reference to the original class instance
        String one = originalClassReference.one;
        String two = originalClassReference.two;
        String three = originalClassReference.three;
        TestMethod(one, two, three);
    }
}
```

And your main code effectively becomes:

```
BackgroundWorker bw = new BackgroundWorker();

// Note: these may become field members to remain visible to the closure class
String one = resultFromSomeMethod();
String two = resultFromOtherMethod();
String three = resultFromThirdMethod();

var closure = new AnonymousClosureClass();
bw.DoWork += closure.AnonymousLambda;
```

Finally, worth noting, this is not how the actual generated closure code is named or looks, at all.

Comment: I understand that, but the TestMethod parameters would not be in scope.

Comment: You wrapped the `TestMethod` parameters in the function that matches the signature of the delegate, so it works. This is also known as an Adapter Pattern, though a loose example of one.

Comment: @KyleM "the TestMethod parameters would not be in scope." That's called a *closure*. The anonymous method is a member of an anonymous class. That class will contain fields that reference whatever variables will be needed to call the `TestMethod`. It's said that the lambda "closes over your local variables".

Comment: I am saying that in your translation above, it wouldn't work because the args to "TestMethod" are not in scope. I'm not sure what your response to my first comment meant :( .

Comment: You've wrapped `TestMethod` which **does not** match the event handler signature, within an anonymous method that **does** conform for the event handler signature.

Comment: The arguments are all string literals.  They don't really have a scope.  If you're *actually* passing different values, not just string literals, then in that case they do have scope, they will be closed over, and that comment is relevant.

Comment: @Servy They weren't intended to be string literals or I wouldn't have made them function parameters. I should've used a better example like TestMethod(String one, String two, String three). Everyone, thanks, I will review this material more.

Comment: @DavidHaney Thanks, I get what you're saying about how the TestMethod is wrapped and it is helpful. My comment was that your "translates to AnonymousLambda" code above couldn't possibly work since TestMethod's three String parameters would be out of scope. Dcastro and Servy have clarified by saying that this is implemented as a closure (see my question update). If you can update your translation code that would be helpful, I think. But your answer is helpful regardless.

Comment: @KyleM sorry to disagree, but my translation code is correct. Try it. Copy-paste it in and run it as `bw.DoWork += AnonymousLambda` and watch it run.

Comment: See my updated question. How could the Strings "one", "two", and "three" possibly be in-scope for the example you've given? Sorry if I'm being daft. (Note: with dcastro's explanation it makes more sense I think)

Comment: This is a different question. as @Servy and dcastro pointed out, the compiler creates a closure out of this. It's prone to errors when looping is involved, so you generally want to avoid it. I'll update my question to show you what it does.

Comment: @DavidHaney I think you're referring to the `foreach` issue. For the following code, the code generated by the compiler would reuse the variable `x` for all 10 iterations: `foreach(var x in tenItems){ ... }`. So, if lambdas were created inside the loop, and they referred to `x`, all 10 lambdas would close over `x` and be pointing to the same variable `x`. I'm pretty sure that issue has been fixed with the release of either C# 4.0 or 5.0. `foreach` now creates a brand new variable for each iteration.

Comment: @DavidHaney You don't want to avoid closures.  Closures are an *amazing* tool that provide a lot of power, and can greatly simplify code.  You simply need to realize that closures close over variables, not values, and code accordingly.  Avoiding such an amazing feature simply because of that is extremely wasteful.

Comment: @Servy I guess that's a good perspective and point. I generally don't find myself closing over things, because my state is usually in a case like this passed as a custom `EventArgs` object exposing the variables vs closure variables. :)

Comment: @DavidHaney Your example of closures is wrong.  It demonstrates closing over *values* not closing over *variables*.

Comment: @Servy can you edit it to be appropriate? I'm not sure I'm up on the difference.

Comment: @Servy are you talking about lazy eval and Funcs over the variables? If so I can update.

Comment: @DavidHaney Modifications to a *variable* (note this is different from mutating an instanced referenced by a reference type variable) will be reflected in the closed over variable after the execution of the lambda.  Your implementation doesn't account for that.

Comment: @DavidHaney Not in the least.  Executing the lambda twice does not compute those strings twice.  They are computed before the lambda executes.  Assigning a value to a closed over variable is in no way deferred due tot he fact that someone closes over it later on.

Comment: @Servy Why don't you just update it to be a correct example. I think maybe the community can benefit from this and I'm not the only one struggling with how delegates, lambdas, and closures all come into play here...

Comment: @Servy well then I'm a tad lost on what you mean, and would appreciate any input.

Comment: [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21890787/how-closure-in-c-sharp-works-when-using-lambda-expressions/21891893#21891893) is an example of something functionally equivalent to what the C# compiler will do.

Comment: I'm not sure then how my original example was incorrect?

Comment: @DavidHaney You copied the values of the variables to the closure class, thus closing over the values, and not the variables.  Changes to the variables after creating the lambda, but before it is executed, wouldn't be observed in the lambda.  Changes to the variables within the lambda wouldn't be observed within the caller.  The expectation of closing over values, rather than variables, is also the cause of virtually every single bug with closures (which is why you proportionally don't use them).

Comment: @Servy ahh - I get what you're saying. I think I'm on track now.

Comment: @Servy and David, thanks so much for sticking with me. I think this answer and these comments will be helpful to someone in the future and they were certainly helpful for me.

Comment: Still not right.  At this point `originalClassReference` isn't in scope in the closure class.  That's close to what would be done *if you were accessing fields/properties*.  Basically you just close over `this` and then access it's members.  But here they're *not* fields, they're local variables, so you cannot access them from an instance of the class they are defined in.

Comment: So how would it happen? I am at a loss.

Answer (score 5):

The `TestMethod` is being called from the (a,b) function.

Look at it this way instead:

```
BackgroundWorker bw = new BackgroundWorker();
bw.DoWork += DoWorkFunc;

void DoWorkFunc(object a, EventArgs b)
{
    TestMethod("", "", "");
}
```

Answer (score 5):

The parameters are defined in the `(a,b)` portion of your code. These correspond to `object sender` and `DoWorkEventArgs e`. That is, your lambda is similar to the following code:

```
BackgroundWorker bw = new BackgroundWorker();
bw.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(MyFunction);


void MyFunction(object a, DoWorkEventArgs b)
{
    TestMethod("", "", "");
}
```

The fact that you're not using the parameters, or returning the value of `TestMethod`, is irrelevant.

(compare to a [`Func<int, int>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549151%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)`myFunc = c => c + 1` lambda equivalent)

```
int MyFunction(int c)
{
    return c + 1;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

The delegate's arguments are simply unused. Lambda is an equivalent of the following method:

```
void LambdaMethod(object a, DoWorkEventArgs b)
{
    TestMethod("", "", "");
}
```