# Why ToolStripMenuItem.Click event handlers show the same content?

Tags: c#, eventhandler

I have a tree view which has a node named "FTPServerListNode".

The "FTPServerListNode" has 2 FTPServerNode , 1 is "serverId1" and other 1 is "serverId2".

Both FTPServerListNode and FTPServerNode are extended from TreeNode.

Each child node has a ToolStripMenuItem.

Each ToolStripMenuItem has its own on click event handler.

These 2 on click event handler just show the node name.

However, I found that both event handlers show the same content(i.e. "serverId2").

Here is my source code.

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace ToolStripMenuItemTest
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            treeView1.Nodes.Add(new FtpServerListNode());
        }
    }
    internal class FtpServerNode : TreeNode
    {
        internal FtpServerNode(string serverDesc, string serverId)
        {
            this.Text = serverDesc;
            this.Name = serverId;
        }
    }
    internal class FtpServerListNode : TreeNode
    {
        internal FtpServerListNode()
        {
            FtpServerNode ftpServerNode = new FtpServerNode("serverDesc1", "serverId1");

            var nN= ftpServerNode.Name;
            ToolStripMenuItem removeServerToolStrip = new ToolStripMenuItem();
            removeServerToolStrip.Text = "Remove This FTP Server";
            removeServerToolStrip.Click += (sender, e) => MessageBox.Show(nN);
            ftpServerNode.ContextMenuStrip = new ContextMenuStrip();
            ftpServerNode.ContextMenuStrip.Items.Add(removeServerToolStrip);
            this.Nodes.Add(ftpServerNode);

            ftpServerNode = new FtpServerNode("serverDesc2", "serverId2");
            nN= ftpServerNode.Name;
            removeServerToolStrip = new ToolStripMenuItem();
            removeServerToolStrip.Text = "Remove This FTP Server";
            removeServerToolStrip.Click += (sender, e) => MessageBox.Show(nN);
            ftpServerNode.ContextMenuStrip = new ContextMenuStrip();
            ftpServerNode.ContextMenuStrip.Items.Add(removeServerToolStrip);
            this.Nodes.Add(ftpServerNode);
            this.Text = "Root Node";
            this.Expand();
        }
    }
}
```

I attach my project screen for your reference.

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How closure in c# works when using lambda expressions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21890787/how-closure-in-c-sharp-works-when-using-lambda-expressions)

Comment: You changed the nN variable value.  That worked, it now refers to "serverId2" and does so for both Click event handlers.  Using another variable is the simple solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After several trials, the following code works:

```
internal class FtpServerListNode : TreeNode
{
    internal FtpServerListNode()
    {
        SortedDictionary<string, FtpServerNode> ftpServerList = new SortedDictionary<string, FtpServerNode>();
        FtpServerNode ftpServerNode = new FtpServerNode("serverDesc1", "serverId1");
        ftpServerList.Add("serverId1", ftpServerNode);
        ftpServerNode = new FtpServerNode("serverDesc2", "serverId2");
        ftpServerList.Add("serverId2", ftpServerNode);

        foreach (FtpServerNode fn in ftpServerList.Values)
        {
            ToolStripMenuItem removeServerToolStrip = new ToolStripMenuItem();

            removeServerToolStrip.Text = "Remove This FTP Server " + fn.Name;
            removeServerToolStrip.Click += (sender, e) => MessageBox.Show(fn.Name);
            fn.ContextMenuStrip = new ContextMenuStrip();
            fn.ContextMenuStrip.Items.Add(removeServerToolStrip);
            this.Nodes.Add(fn);
        }
        this.Text = "Root Node";
        this.Expand();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please change your event handler to

```
var mName = ftpServerNode.Name;
removeServerToolStrip.Click += (sender, e) => MessageBox.Show(mName);
```

You run into a Modified Closure problem: 
https://www.jetbrains.com/help/resharper/AccessToModifiedClosure.html

Comment: It does not work. I have updated the question details.

Comment: I updated my answer with more specific solution and explanation.

Comment: It still does not work, I have updated my code for your reference. I am using Visual Studio Community 2015 edition.

Comment: Please use nN1 and nN2, otherwise you get the same problem! You should avoid using the same variable two both lambda expression. That is the problem.