# C#: lambda that evaluates parameter on creating, not on executing

Tags: c#, lambda, parameters, evaluation

This is the code:

```
pages[i][0] = create("[Back]", () => setMenu(pages[i - 1]));
```

Problem is that when the `Action` is executed, it uses the `i` from the specific scope, and since I use it for my `for`, it will be always the max value. In my case the parameter becomes `2`, even if the lambda was created with `1`. To get around this I did that:

```
var forcedCopy = i - 1;
pages[i][0] = create("[Back]", () => setMenu(pages[forcedCopy]));
```

Is there any way to get around this ugly trick? I want to pass `myFunc(0)`, `myFunc(1)`, etc, not `myFunc(i)`.

Comment: No, there isn't. Creating a manual copy is your best option.

Comment: You are actually passing the variable so this is normal behaviour. You could do this: `var tempInt = i;` and then use tempInt in the lambda (just an example, tempInt is bad naming don't do it)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How closure in c# works when using lambda expressions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21890787/how-closure-in-c-sharp-works-when-using-lambda-expressions)

Comment: Couldn't you create a method that creates that Action? in this you can automatically capture a reference to the page you want (for now I assume some `Page` class). `private Action CreateSetMenuAction(Page p) => () => setMenu(p);`. That said it's normal practice to create a local variable and capture that in a lambda expression.

Comment: @Knoop, I could do this too, but the question was if I can do this without copying.

Comment: Ah I misunderstood the "ugly trick", thought you meant more how it looked, not the inefficiency of it. But then as others have said, no. When you think about it this is logical. You ask for everything to use the same memory space (where the `i` is stored, implied by the non-copying) but you want them to use different values in that shared memory slot...who knows quantum computing with quantum states might make this possible, but for now that seems like a contradiction.